# Making session number related ID matches

Tags: javascript, math

I'm using a software that returns me a unique ID related to asession number, but I can't seem to find how the UID and the given session number are related.

Here are two sets:

**Session 1**

```
Session ID: 2098744
First object ID: 733EAFB5F70B09
Second object ID: 7366ACB5F70B77
```

**Session 2**

```
Session ID: 6438379
First Obj ID: 7349CAFCADA8F9
Second Obj ID: 73AFC9FCADA872
```

For both sessions, target objects are the same. I'm basically trying to generate an ID that is common between those sessions.
I've already tried making the IDs decimals and basic maths functions (+,-,%,*,/...)

Thanks for any further help !

EDIT:
To make it more clear, after formula/function, first object ID should be a value A for both of the sessions, and second object ID should be a value B for both of the sessions.

Comment: What is the software that you are using to generate unique ID?  It's really hard to tell what the problem is if we don't know what you are using.

Comment: @frogcoder it's a software called Pronote used for school managment. They returns a Session ID which is 7 digits in base 10, and each object has a unique ID (presumably in HEX) which is unique to that session too.

Comment: I am sorry I don't know anything about Pronote.  The way you talk about object ID is weird though.  It's ok to generate ID, but once generated, it should be saved somewhere and restored again when needed next time.  This way the ID would stay the same across different sessions.

Comment: @frogcoder that's the actual problem. I know in the backend they have ID that are global, but the Pronote API sends back Object ID related to the Session. I guess I still have a lot to try before finding...